# Symfony2 - What's the difference between DependencyInjection and Services?

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection

Well, the question is in the title, but to sum it up, I'm not sure to understand what's the difference between `DependencyInjection` and `Service`, as they are both called the same way (by invoking them using the container, e.g. `$this->get('my_service_or_dependency')` from a controller).

I looked into the docs but I couldn't find a clear answer to that question.

Thanks for your insights!

Comment: Agree with the Tomasz Madeyski's answer. Perhaps a better question would be about the difference/relation between DependencyInjection and ServiceLocator patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR: DI is a design pattern, service is a class**

It's hard to compare one to another. `Dependency Injection` is design pattern in which you don't hardcode dependencies in your class but you inject them into your class (most likely as a parameter to your constructor).

Example (using `Dependency Injection`):

```
class someController
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }
}
```

The same example without `Dependency Injection`:

```
class someController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->doctrine = new Doctrine(); 
        //there's no such thing as new Doctrine() but this is just an example
    }
}
```

In second example whenever you want to change your `ObjectManager` implementation (for example switch `Doctrine` to `Propel` you need to refactor your code. So your code has dependency hardcoded.

In first example you inject your `ObjectManager` object, so when you want to switch to another implementation you just change configuration (in `Symfony` it would be `services.yml` most likely)

`Service` in this case is a class (`SomeController`) which get dependency injected (see [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#what-is-a-service) for better definition)